# If $|\alpha^N| = 1 + k|g|$ for $g \in G_{\alpha}$, then $g$ fixes a point on every $N$-orbit that it stabilizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite transitive permutation group, suppose $p$ does not divide $G_{\alpha}$ and that $1 \ne P \unlhd G$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$. Let $\Delta := \alpha^P$ be an orbit of $P$ and suppose that $g \in G_{\alpha}$ just has the unique fixed point $\alpha$ on $\Delta$ and acts semi-regular on $\Delta \setminus \{\alpha\}$, i.e. every orbit of size $> 1$ has size $|g|$. Then $|P| = |\Delta| = 1 + k\cdot |g|$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$.

> Why does this implies that $g$ fixes a point on every other orbit of $P$ that it stabilizes?

If $\Gamma := \beta^P$ would be another orbit of $P$ such that $\Gamma^g = \Gamma$, then $g \in G_{\beta}P$. But why has $g$ to fix some point in $\Gamma$? Just the numerical relations do not seem to imply that, for example if $|P| = 7$ and $|g| = 6$, then the orbits of $g$ on $\Gamma$ might have sizes $2,2,3$ and so no fixed point, but on $\Delta$ we might have $7 = 1 + 6$ for the orbit sizes.

Comment: Your hypotheses in the first paragraph imply that $C_P(g^i)=1$ whenever $g^i \ne 1$. But if you had the situation in your final sentence, then $C_P(g^2) \ne 1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt In this situation $g^2$ has to fix two points on $\Gamma$ as we have two orbits of size $2$, so we have $7 = 2 + 3m$ by an orbit decomposition for $\langle g^2 \rangle$, and this is not possible. But why does this implies $C_P(g^2) \ne 1$, and how to make a general argument out of it?

Comment: Okay, I see it as the stabilizers act similar on $P$ by conjugation as on $\Omega$, if $g^2$ has two fixed points on $\Gamma$ we must have $C_P(g^2) \ne 1$. But still how to make a general argument out of it. Suppose some $g^i$ fixes some $\gamma \in \Gamma$. Does this implies that it has to fix a second point on $\Gamma$?? Or that we have some power $g^i$ of $g$ that fixes two points?

Comment: All the nontrivial orbits of $g$ must have length $|g|$, so it must fix a point in each orbit.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, but why that? Is there any easy explanation for it...

Comment: I explained why in my first comment.

Comment: @DerekHolt I see that we must have $C_P(g^i) = 1$; but $g$ just acts similar on $\Delta$ as on $P$ by conjugation; but I do not see that it acts similar on every other orbit as on $P$ by conjugation? So how could we transfer our knowledge about $C_P(g)$ to the action of $g$ on $\Gamma$...

Comment: At least I see that $g$ acts on both orbits permutation isomorphic: If $\Gamma = \Delta^h$ for some $h \in G$, then by $\lambda(\alpha^n) := \alpha^{nh}$ and $\varphi(g) := g^h$ we have $\lambda(\alpha^n)^{\varphi(g)} = \alpha^{ngh} = \varphi(\alpha^{ng})$ so that $\langle g \rangle$ and $\langle g^h \rangle$ act permutation isomorphic on two $P$-orbits, hence induce the same orbit structure and $g^i$ fixes $\delta \in \Delta$ iff $(g^h)^i$ fixes $\delta^h \in \Gamma$; but still that does not gives that $g$ itself has the same orbit structure on $\Gamma$...

Comment: As I said in my first comment, if $g$ had a nonregular orbit of length $i$ say, then $C_P(g^i)$ would be nontrivial.

Comment: On the orbit $\Delta$ I see that, as the action of $g$ on $P$ is similar to its action on $\Delta$; but on a different orbit $\Gamma$ we do not have this connection. So what is the crucial information connecting the centralizer of some power of $g$ to its action on $\Gamma$?

Comment: Let $\Gamma$ be an orbit of $P$. 1. If $g$ does not fix any point of $\Gamma$, then $\langle g \rangle$ has an orbit of length $i$ on $\Gamma$ for some $i$ with $1 < i < |g|$. 2. $1 \ne g^i$ and $g^i$ fixes at least $i$ points of $\Gamma$. 3. $|C_P(g^i)| \ge i$, contradicting $|C_G(g^i)|=1$. Which of those three steps do you not understand?

Comment: Step 3, that $|C_P(g^i)| \ge i$ if $g^i$ fixes $i$ points on $\Gamma$; that this implies that it must fix $i$ elements of $P$ by conjugation. I think we cannot suppose that both actions (of $g^i$ on $\Gamma$ and of $g^i$ on $P$) are equivalent, so I do not see how this follows...

Comment: In general, if a permutation group $G$ has a regular normal subgroup $N$ and $G = N \langle g \rangle$ where $g$ fixes exactly $k>0$ points, then $|C_N(g)|=k$.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for your patience! I collected everything up and wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Derek's hints I collect what is written in the comments. The notation as in the question.

**Lemma**: If $N \unlhd G$ is a regular normal subgroup, then $G_{\alpha}$ acts similar on $\Omega$ as on $N$ by conjugation.

*Proof*: Fix $\alpha \in \Omega$ and define $\lambda : N \to \Omega$ by $\lambda(x) := \alpha^x$. Then for $g \in G_{\alpha}$ we have $\lambda(x^g) = \alpha^{g^{-1}xg} = \alpha^{xg} = \lambda(x)^g$. $\square$

**Corollary**: If $N \unlhd G$ and $g$ fixes exactly $k > 0$ points, we have $|C_P(g)| = k$.

*Proof*: Choose some $g \in G_{\alpha}$, then $x \in C_P(g)$ iff $\lambda(x)^g = \lambda(x)$, hence the claim follows. $\square$

Now for the situation in the question, the assumptions give $C_P(g^i) = 1$ for nontrivial $g^i$. As if $g^i \ne 1$ the subgroup $C_P(g^i)$ acts on the fixed points of $g^i$ on $\Delta$. But by assumption $\alpha$ is the only fixed point of $g^i$ on $\Delta$ and hence every $y \in C_P(g^i)$ has to fix $\alpha$ too, but as $P_{\alpha} = 1$ this implies $C_P(g^i) = 1$. But this could also be seen with the Lemma by the assumption about the orbit structure on $\Delta$.

Now let $\Gamma$ be a different orbit of $P$ such that $\Gamma^g = \Gamma$. If $g$ fixes no point of $\Gamma$, then as $|\Gamma| = 1 + k|g|$ it could not act semi-regular on $\Gamma$, hence we have some $g^i \ne 1$ that fixes a point of $\Gamma$. Now look at the cycle structure induced by $g$ on $\Gamma$. The different orbits correspond to distinct cycles and by the above we have some cycle of length $i$ with $1 < i < |g|$; and we see that $g^i$ must fix at least $i$ points, i.e. all the ones in the cycle of length $i$. Also $P$ acts regular on its $P$-orbit $\Gamma$; and together with the Lemma the action of $g^i$ on $P$ by conjugation is equivalent to its action on $\Gamma$, hence $|C_P(g^i)| = i > 1$. A contradiction. So $g$ itself must fix a point in $\Gamma$.